# How to register a license for a software in India?

Tags: software, licensing, open-source-software, india

I have decided that I want to go ahead with the AGPL license for my software. What is the procedure that one has to go through in India so that the LICENSE holds in court. Will a LICENSE file along with code be enough or do we have to register it at any other office or organization?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a bureaucratic process and not the law.

Comment: If this question gets closed here, then it might be on-topic on https://opensource.stackexchange.com

Comment: Law cannot be separated from bureaucracy. Bureaucratic process is the practical counterpart of law. It's like saying computer science is not about code, it's about logic.

Comment: I'm not sure if Indian law with regards to software is different, but in most of the world you don't have to register legal documents, you just draw them up with terms that you want and that are aligned with local law, then if the issue comes up you fight it in court.

Comment: Bureaucracy can exist without regard to law, and vice versa, and often does. There might be a law authorising the creation of a department and allowing it to spend money, but whether it's the manager or the supervisor that can approve purchasing of printer paper is purely bureaucracy, not law. Same with this.

Comment: Something written on a piece of paper has to comply with human nature. Every scholar in statemanship has like Kautilya has shown that all rules must be written by distrusting people. If one writes a law which is detached from human nature, we get independent bureaucracy and law in which the law exists only on paper.

Comment: And human nature as a whole is extremely difficult to change. Not even the most influential people can change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Indian law [you own copyright in your code](http://www.legalserviceindia.com/article/l195-Copyright-Law-in-India.html) as soon as it is created, without any need for registration formalities. You are then free to license other people to use that code as you see fit. The AGPL is one way of doing this.

So the answer to your question is that you don't need to register anything. Just put copyright messages at the top of your source code files (not really necessary, but it helps clarify which files are included) and distribute the code with the license file.

Comment: Yes, in theory. The resource you've linked is excellent. We can register copyright with copyright registrar for better recognition.